# Software for drawing LaTeX flowcharts and control system diagrams

Tags: flow-charts, charts, software

Tell me the full program software for drawing LaTeX diagrams and control systems schemes. For example:

[image]

I know TeXample and Overleaf, but I own it badly, because writing these schemes in the programming language for a long time and is enjoyable, but I want something in the type of Visio, naturally with the possibilities of LaTeX on editing and formatting formulas and plots.

I would be grateful for the advice and help.

Comment: For `tikz-cd` based diagrams, there is yishn's [tikzcd-editor](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de). Or maybe, [TikZiT](https://tikzit.github.io) suits your needs?

Comment: @JasperHabicht

Maybe, LaTeXDraw suitable for this?

Comment: There is also the diagram editor [Dia](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dia-installer/) which can export to LaTeX (either PGF or PSTricks).

Comment: @Marijn

Do you own this package well? Could you draw that the scheme that I brought in my question and show me?

Comment: I have used it occasionally, I'm not very experienced with it. But it has dozens of shape collections, two for circuits specifically and several others for electronics, so your diagram would certainly be possible/easy. I would suggest that you try yourself to see if you find it convenient.

Comment: We write article with colleagues and want to beautifully present all the schemes and diagrams that we have. The possibilities of Visio in this regard did not advance for many years.

Comment: To get the best looking result I would recommend to write the LaTeX code yourself, for example with `tikz-cd`. It is difficult to learn at first but you will be able to do it faster after some practise. Specifying coordinates, distances, sizes etc. in code is much more precise than drawing it with a tool, so the result will be better aligned, more consistent, easier to modify later, and easier to integrate with LaTeX notation inside the diagram and with the flow of the document in general (for example no external files or tools are required).

Comment: @Marijn

I have never done this before. Could you make a simple sample code as an answer, which draws the scheme specified in the question. It could serve for me a good starting point.

Comment: You can find many examples online as a starting point, such as https://texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/circuitikz/. One simple example that looks a bit like the one you want is https://texample.net/tikz/examples/power-electronics-solar-system/. Also the circuitikz [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf) has many small examples to get you started. Note that this site is not a free code writing service, if you have a specific issue with your code then you are welcome to ask but asking for a full diagram from scratch is not the goal of this site.

Comment: I can't insert latex formula with Latex Drow. My code is not compliant.